# How to avoid NULL in Map.get() method

Tags: apex

I'm getting the null pointer exception in for loop

> FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a
>   null object

. Is there a way to filter null in Map.get()?

```
Map<ID,List<AccountPartner>>actIdPartnerMap= new Map<ID,List<AccountPartner>>();

// (populate map here...)

if (!actIdPartnerMap.isEmpty()) {
    if(null != p:actIdPartnerMap.get(usr.AccountId)) {
        for(AccountPartner p:actIdPartnerMap.get(usr.AccountId)) {
            AccountShare acp = new AccountShare();
            acp.AccountId=p.AccountFromId;
            acp.UserOrGroupId=usr.id;
            acp.AccountAccessLevel='Edit';
            acp.CaseAccessLevel='Edit';
            acp.OpportunityAccessLevel='Edit';
            sharingObjects.add(acp);
            system.debug(logginglevel.INFO,'InInnerLoop*******'+acp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I presume you're populating the map between the first and second lines? Otherwise, I'd naturally expect this map to be empty.

Comment: I'm actually populating my map in a different loop before specified loop, I didn't post entire code here. my scenario is when a user is not part of the Account sharing team then need to create the new sharing object for the insert. So, before creating the new object, i need to check in the map to make sure.

Comment: If that's the case, sounds like you need to use a try-catch block to catch the null pointer exception.

Comment: @crmprogdev No, try-catch definitely should not be used here. There's no reason for a try-catch block except to use it to mask the real problem.

Comment: Sounded like he was trying to see if the sharing record existed in the map and was getting null returned for the value. If so, that would require a try-catch. But I may not be following all of the use case.

Comment: What is the line that's failing? What is the statement of that line? There's several things that could be null here: `p`, `usr` (you don't show us how you initialize it). You need to know what variable is null to fix it. Also, I don't quite get this syntax: `if(null != p:actIdPartnerMap.get(usr.AccountId))`

Comment: @crmprogdev - No try catch, simply check if the key exists. Since the OP is populating the map do not add keys with no values. If the problem is that a value should exist for a given key then OP will need to troubleshoot the events before this loop. May also need to check if usr is null as it could be that as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your code could be simplified:

```
AccountPartner[] partners = actIdPartnerMap.get(usr.AccountId);
if(partners != null) {
    for(AccountPartner p: partners) {
        sharingObjects.add(
            new AccountShare(
                AccountId=p.AccountFromId,
                UserOrGroupId=usr.id,
                AccountAccessLevel='Edit',
                CaseAccessLevel='Edit',
                OpportunityAccessLevel='Edit')
        );
    }
}
```

Secondly, you'll want to make sure that `usr` is not null. There's no other way you could get a System.NullPointerException other than if that variable were null.

Comment: Yay for much cleaner code!

Comment: Thank you All, It worked. Putting into the list and then checking the Null. resolved the issue.